# manage docker containers in cockpit without root

Tags: centos, docker

I have a docker server (CentOS 7) that has cockpit installed and wish to use cockpit to manage docker containers. My main account on the server is able to use sudo elevate permissions on the system. But when I log into the server, even with reuse my password for privilege task option enabled, I still cannot access my docker containers with cockpit.

I have enabled my root account and enabled the docker engine and it wont appear in cockpit, I had made a docker group and added my account to the docker group and the docker command works without the sudo command.

so, what im trying to accomplish is to use docker containers in cockpit without using root (sudo is fine)